# multiple mouse events not triggering

Tags: google-maps, events, mouse

I am using google maps api.  I want to have two mouse events ready to trigger at one time.  Below is a code snipit.

```
function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 13,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var polyOptions = {
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 3  }
    poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
    poly.setMap(map);
    // Add a listener for the click event
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addLatLng);
}

function addLatLng(event) {
var path = poly.getPath();

if(!draw)
{
    path.push(event.latLng);
    path.push(event.latLng);
    draw = true;
// Add a new marker at the new plotted point on the polyline.

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event.latLng,
            title: '#' + path.getLength(),
            map: map  });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', moveTrackLine);
}
else
{
        path.push(event.latLng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                    position: event.latLng,
                                                    title: '#' + path.getLength(),
                                                    map: map  });
        draw = false;
}
}

function moveTrackLine(event) {

var path = poly.getPath();
// replace the old point with a new one to update the track
path.pop();
path.push(event.latLng);
}
```

When I click on the map the first time I see a marker placed on the map.  Then when the mouse is moved I see the polyline update and follow my curser correctly.  Next if I click on the map I do not see a marker placed on the map nor do I ever go into the addLatLng function.  Thanks in advance for your help and time.
-tim

Answer (score 0):

set the `clickable`-option of the polyline to false.

The issue: As soon as the mousemove-event is applied to the map, you will not be able to click on the map anymore, because below the mouse-cursor is always the polyline.

When you set the clickable-option of the polyline to false, the polyline does not respond to mouse-events and the click-event will be passed to the map.